# What is "wont' let me post for 4 hours" about?

Tags: support

One of our new members [said today](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15350/arcgis-python-ctypes-c-dll-tool-cancels-itself-why/15358#comment20171_15358) *"Actually, thanks for your help but I have an answer now. Alas stackexchange won't let me post it for another 4 hours!"*

What is he talking about and why can't he post? I don't remember encountering anything like that, so I presume it's a new anti-spam measure or similar. I'd like to know the specifics of what this measure is, so I can help people when they run into it.

Comment: A SE limitation for new users with less than 100 rep.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

New users who have less than 100 reputation cannot post answers to *their own questions* within the first eight hours of posting said question. This was implemented back in April 2011.

This was devised because the vast majority of new user self-answers were not answers. Rather, they were message-board style responses from those unfamiliar with the difference between a Q&A site and a forum. As such, this stops them from doing so, and hopefully guides them towards using comments where it would be appropriate.

It does bar the occasional legitimate self-answer, but the occurrence is generally infrequent.

Comment: Thanks for the concise and official answer.